# how to achieve the navigation back button action on ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, navigation

I have use navigation to build my uiviewcontroller(A → B).

But I need to change the back method.

I will hidden < Back button.

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Then I bulid a new tool bar on the bottom and add a Bar Button item (name home) on the tool bar.

I had set

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backHomeBtn;
```

But I don't know how to achieve the same action about the native "＜Back" button effect.

If I use Triggered Segue Action push,

I feel it is wrong method. Because I fell the stack will push a new viewcontroller.

How to build a same action like the navigation back button.

Thank you very much.

============================

I found answer:

If back to A, we can use

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewController］
```

If want to jump to direct uiviewercontroller.

we can use

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

or

```
 for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
     if ([controller isKindOfClass:[otherUIViewercontrollerClassName  class]]) {
         [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For going back from B to A, make an Action event and write this method in B View Controller and connect your back back button with this event.

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

When your going like A → B → C and want to get back to A from C, you can use this to to reach to the Root Controller.

```
-(IBAction)unwindToRootController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

Declare this action in your header(.h) file and then just connect your Button with the Exit Responder and select this event.

Comment: thank you very much~ I found other answer , I post on my question.